# Braces and Brackets not working in Windows 7 x32

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a `Logitech Compact Keyboard K300` keyboard with Windows 7 x32, but when I hit keys from <kbd>~</kbd> to  <kbd>|</kbd>  (including <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>[</kbd>), nothing is typed, I need to enetr <kbd>Alt + 123</kbd> to get the brace.

Note: I have a dual boot with win7 x64 and downloading MS Mouse and Keyboard center seemed to fixe it, unlike in x86. I am using the `azerty` keyboard since I am french.

Comment: Veryify your using the correct keyboard layout.  You might have the correct language pack but the keyboard layout can be set to something entirely different then what the physical keyboard actually is.  You need to verify Windows actually supports AZERTY its possible it does not.  The good news you can use AutoHotKeys add support for it.

Comment: @Ramhound how to check that? Can AutoHotKey tell it?